# Add a file path at the beginning of my text

Tags: file, text, directory, notepad++

I have a lot of .text files and i can't just go and copy paste the file path into one at a time. Is there a way to add file path at the beginning of every .text doc open; their path into their file.

Comment: You have to do that job with a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: I just thought that there'd be a manual way in notepad ++. but php or javascript i understand